# How to set valueFormatter for Markers in iOS-charts

Tags: ios-charts

For the y-axis we can do something like this:

```
chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = SomeCustomTimeFormatter()
```

But how do we change the format for markers (the popups that appear when you tap a data point)? I am using BalloonMarker from the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use BalloonMarker from the sample you can update the code in this line

```
open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
{
    //setLabel(String(entry.y)) //change label value in this line to use your desired format
   setLabel(String("\(Int(entry.y)/60):\(Int(entry.y)%60)"
}

open func setLabel(_ newLabel: String)
{
        label = newLabel 
        //.......
}
```

and set the marker for your chartview

```
let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 186/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1), font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!, textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 25.0, right: 7.0))
 marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75.0, height: 35.0)
charts.marker = marker
```